# Getting data to appBar - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch data to api for the Appbar but stuck with the await / async

What I am trying to do:

```
getUserName(id) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  String token;
  token = prefs.get('Token');
  String url = "https://apiurl";
  http.post(
    url,
    headers: {'authorization': 'bearer' + token},
    body: {'thread': id.toString()},
  ).then((response) {
    print("Response body: ${response.body}");
    return response.body;
  });
}
```

And I call it while trying to build:

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(getUserInfo(widget.id)),    
        ....
```

However I end up with:
instance of future dynamic

What I understand I should somehow wait for the result. But await is not accepted if I try:

```
await getUserInfo(widget.id);
```

Comment: i think you should be call setState() after get value from post method.

Comment: At complete loss here where I should do that? If by any chance you could share bit more light to it ..thanks :)

Comment: String id; value = await getUserInfo(widget.id).then(setState(id = value))

Comment: @darkness I can't use await ..then doesn't seem to help me at all neither as I explain in a reply to answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First await your call to `http.post`

```
Future<String> getUserName(id) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  String token;
  token = prefs.get('Token');
  String url = "https://apiurl";
  var response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: {'authorization': 'bearer' + token},
    body: {'thread': id.toString()},
  );

  return response.body
}
```

Then could use something like this

```
// Declare _userInfo at state class level and run this on build or initState
if (_userInfo == null) {
  getUserInfo(id).then((userInfo) => setState(() => _userInfo = userInfo));
}
```

Then

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(_userInfo),
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately even in setState userInfo is null. Tried to print it out there instead of setting _userInfo. I'm declaring _userInfo at the beginning of the state class and trying to run if in the build or initState, neither help. If I print out some info it seems that the response is not been waited for. If I set it in build it causes infinite loop, _userInfo never gets set. Api is of course giving the proper response, so is getUserInfo()

Comment: I missed how you were calling `http.post`. Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you! Indeed did the trick. Learned so much from this answer in general for the future. Big thanks again :)